# Virtual scanner for documents and images

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, images, scanning

Is there a free offline virtual scanner (for Windows XP and above) that allows end-users to import a wide selection of image formats (e.g. tiff, jpg, png, bmp) and document format (esp. PDF) and allow some form of management (e.g. sort and edit them), before importing into any scanning application.

The free virtual scanner acts as a scanner which allows you to pull images from your documents (image and document format), instead of from a physical device.